# Cantor staircase function is not BV if we redefine it to be zero outside the Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory

The Cantor staircase function has bounded variation.

Is it true that Cantor staircase function is *not* BV *if we redefine it to be zero outside the Cantor set*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Let $C$ denote the Cantor set, $c(x)$ the Cantor staircase function, and $f(x)$ your modified Cantor staircase function that is zero outside the Cantor set. There exist infinitely many points $x \in C$ for which $c(x)> \frac{1}{2}$, and thus $f(x)>\frac{1}{2}$. Between any two points $x, y \in C$, we can find $z \notin C$ (and we have $f(z)=0$).

Now bounded variation on $[0,1]$ says there exists $M>0$ such that for any choice of values $0=x_0<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n=1$, we have 
$$|f(x_1)-f(x_0)| + |f(x_2)-f(x_1)|+\cdots+|f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})| \leq M.$$
To show $f$ is *not* BV, you need to show that for any $M$, you can choose values of $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n$ so that the sum above exceeds $M$. Do you see where to go from here?

Comment: Not really. What does that "mean value property" imply?

Comment: I've expanded my answer a bit.

Comment: Could you explain a bit further why having "zero" instead of 1/2 outside of the Cantor set makes a difference in the computation? What is the general principle that can be extrapolated: For example,  what if we define instead of the standard Cantor function, another one: the one that maps $0$ to $0$, $1/3$ to $2/3$ instead of $1/2$, $2/3$ to $1/3$ instead of $1/2$, and $1$ to $1$ (and interpolates linearly)? Why is this of bounded variation, but not if we redefine it to be zero outside of the Cantor set?

Comment: Having zero outside the Cantor set matters because if $x\in C$ with $x>\frac12$ and $y \notin C$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq \frac12$. And my point is we can cram as many such $x$ and $y$ as we like in the interval $[0,1]$ alternating between points in $C$ and points not in $C$. So we can make the sum in the definition of BV as large as we like.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much.